# A geometric application of Benford's law

Tags: graphics, probability-or-statistics, geometry, iteration, interactive

I would like some help solving the following problem using Mathematica: Show that, no matter what the initial area of an equilateral triangle is, the sequence of areas (painted in black) of the figures produced by the iterations that transform the original triangle into the Sierpinski triangle satisfies Benford's Law
To demonstrate that the sequence of areas (painted black) of the figures produced by the iterations that transform the original equilateral triangle into the Sierpinski triangle satisfies Benford's Law, follow these steps:
Step 1: First, I defined a function that generates the Sierpinski triangle by iterations. I tried to use recursion for this purpose, but it didn't work:

```
sierpinski[triangle_] := Module[{midpoints},
  midpoints = (#[[1]] + #[[2]])/2 & /@ Partition[triangle, 2, 1];
  Join @@ (Flatten /@ {{triangle[[1]], midpoints[[1]], midpoints[[3]]},
     {midpoints[[1]], triangle[[2]], midpoints[[2]]},
     {midpoints[[3]], midpoints[[2]], triangle[[3]]}})]
```

Step 2: Generating Sierpinski Triangles
I tried to generate a series of Sierpinski triangles by iteratively applying the sierpinski function. I started with an equilateral triangle and tried to generate several iterations. Again, I was not successful:

```
initialTriangle = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}};
iterations = 7; (* You can change the number of iterations as desired *)

sierpinskiTriangles = NestList[sierpinski, initialTriangle, iterations];
```

Step 3: Calculating and Displaying Areas
Calculate the areas of the Sierpinski triangles and then extract the first digit of each area:

```
areas = Area /@ sierpinskiTriangles;
firstDigits = IntegerDigits[First@RealDigits[areas, 10, 1], 10];
```

Step 4: Analyze Compliance with Benford's Law
To verify if the sequence of first digits satisfies Benford's Law, I tried to create a histogram and compare it to the expected distribution:

```
expectedDistribution = Table[Log10[1 + 1/n], {n, 1, 9}];

Histogram[firstDigits, {0.5, 9.5, 1}, "Probability",
  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], 
    Point /@ Transpose[{Range[1, 9], expectedDistribution}]}]
```

I request help in correcting the codes, if the solution is on the right track.
Thanks

Comment: Domen made a comment about me putting what I had tried to do. I deleted the previous post and posted again with my code attempts that didn't work. It's about these codes that I'm looking for help. Thanks